# How to disable all category pages?

Tags: articles, category, googlebots

I have a Joomla site and I would like to hide the category pages. Google is indexing some of them with a number before.

For example, I have a product category and the `mydomain.com/2-products` page is being indexed.

On the page, Joomla is nesting all of the articles in that category.

Comment: You can check this link. it may help. https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

If you mean disable by noindex, then go to CONTENT->CATEGORIES, enter a needed category (products), go to the tab PUBLISHING, find ROBOTS drop down list and choose noindex/nofollow.

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there is category page where your articles are indexed as category wise. If you have created a menu for category then you can disable that then it will be closed.